# Flask authentication using LDAP

Tags: python, ldap, flask

I've searched an answer for this but have found nothing - maybe because it's so obvious.  But I want to make sure.

What is the correct way to authenticate users using an LDAP server in a Flask web app?

[This link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/authentication/) describes 4 authentication methods, so along the same lines, do I just need to write an LDAP auth decorator?

(The reason I'm asking is to see whether I can make a Flask clone of my Django app)

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to write your own decorator which checks the authentication.

In this decorator you should call the wrapped function if a user is authenticated. If not you should return a default page reminding the user to login.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a decorator, but it's a sensible thing to do, as it makes it easy to "tag" those routes that you want to require authentication.

Otherwise you'll be adding a lot more code whenever you want to implement some sort of authentication for a route.